# Generate image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to create an image in OpenCV by gathering the points stored in a Point Cloud in PCL.

My points in PCL are not integers, but doubles. Usually, they vary from -0.5 to 0.5 x/y coordinates and I want them to show in an OpenCV window.

What I'm doing so far is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < point_cloud_pared_agujero_proj->size(); ++i){
    cv::Point2d a;
    a.x = point_cloud_pared_agujero_proj->at(i).y;
    a.x -= min_point_AABB2.y;
    a.x = (a.x * 400) / (max_point_AABB2.y - min_point_AABB2.y);
    a.y = point_cloud_pared_agujero_proj->at(i).z;
    a.y -= min_point_AABB2.z;
    a.y = (a.y * 400)/(max_point_AABB2.z - min_point_AABB2.z);
    puntos2D.push_back(a);
    plot.at<int>(a) = 0;

}
cv::imshow("primera pared", plot);
```

And this is how I create my variable 'plot'

```
plot = cv::Mat(400, 400, CV_8U, 255);
```

Where `point_cloud_pared_agujero_proj` is the point cloud storing the points and AABB2 is storing the bounding box of those points. I'm multypling by 400
because the output window is 400x400. I'm trying to print the points as black in a white background canvas.

As you can see, I'm using the y and z coordinate. The x is constant as I have projected the 3D points into 2D.

Here's what it should look like:

[image]

And this is my output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How could I see the supposed image in OpenCV?

I'm doing this so after all this, I could dilate the image.

Thank you, Alex.

Comment: Please show also how you create the `plot` object. My guess is it's not a single channel matrix of 32bit signed integers.

Comment: This looks like a pixel being repeated, probably 3 or 4 times. Are you writing a 3/4-channel image and reading it as  a single channel image?

Comment: I get the points from the Point Cloud, that varies from -0.5 to 0.5 usually. I don't know anything about channels.